# C char pointer array in stucts, how to

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bit-manipulation

I have a problem understanding how to access specified places in the char arrays in structs.

```
typedef struct Memory
{
char * bitmap[8];
char * memblock[64];
int i;
//...
}Memblock

int somefunction(void)
Memblock mem;
```

Lets say I've allocated the stuct, and now want to do the bitwise operation on bitmap: `bitmap[0] & 1`;

Tried `*mem->bitmap[0] & 1;` with variations without any luck. Does someone have good explanation how to dereference it?
*PS: I understand how to get bitmap, but not bitmap[i].*

Comment: Is there a reason it's `char* bitmap[8]` instead of `char bitmap[8]`? What you want is to declare an array of `char*` or an array of eight `char`?

Comment: You have a point, there is no reason since it should be only as big as memblock. I'll try fixing that first

Comment: I agree with Adriano - however i guess you would access the member just like any - `mem.bitmap[0]="test";`.

Comment: As others pointed out, note that `char *a[8]` is `sizeof(char*)` times bigger than `char a[8]`. (`sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`).

Comment: Is `mem` of type `Memblock *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `mem` is really meant to be an instance of `struct Memory` and `bitmap` is really meant to be an array of `char *`, the correct syntax to access what `bitmap[i]` points to is

```
*mem.bitmap[i]
```

If you're paranoid about precedence, you could add some parentheses:

```
*(mem.bitmap[i])
```

but both the component selection operator `.` and the subscript operator `[]` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so parentheses are not required in this case.

You would only use the `->` operator if `mem` was a pointer to `struct Memory`.

Having said all that, are you sure that bitmap needs to be an array of pointers to `char` instead of an array of `char`?

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question, even though I now have changed bitmap to an array of chars. I mixed up mem->bitmap with mem.bitmap in my code(a shell), not depending on if mem is a pointer or not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all fix char* bitmap[8] to char bitmap[8].

```
 typedef struct Memory
 {
 char bitmap[8]; 
 char * memblock[64];
 int i;
 //...
 }Memblock

 int somefunction(void)
 Memblock mem;
```

Then instead of using mem->bitmap[0] & 1 you need to use mem.bitmap[0] & 1 ,since mem is not a pointer to Memory.

Comment: and some of the semicolons are missing. I am considering you would fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an array of 8 pointers to characters and another array of 64 pointers to characters in your struct `Memory`. That's possibly not what you intended.

Additionally you dropped some necessary semicolons from the code you show.